# In Magento, how would one go about filtering out simple products from a bundled product?

Tags: php, magento, content-management-system, webshop

A computer is a perfect example. While the customer is assembling their computer, how would one go about adding logic into the equation, so that a predetermined incompatibility between two choices removes the other incompatible option? Think about a certain GPU being incompatible with a certain motherboard, for example.

I've looked everywhere, but I just can't find anything about it. Maybe I'm just not looking right or there really is little information on the subject at hand. Regardless, I would appreciate it if anybody could point me into the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If not all combinations are available or if choices are dependent of other selections, use `configurable product` instead of `bundle product`.

Comment: The options still need to be together individually on a single page, though. I thought this wasn't supported out of the box.

Comment: Configurable product is meant to do this kind of stuff. Is also with all options on a single page.

Comment: A configurable product would not work,  he has a unique problem.   A configurable product would only allow him to sell one product based upon a configuration. He may be able to extended the functionality to allow bundling of configurable products. Or creating a dependency of product attributes on a product level.